# How do I use a Kendo UI grid with server side paging and search form?

Tags: pagination, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid. The grid is built but not displayed on the page until a search form is submitted and a response is returned by the server. The response could result in a large number of rows (depending on the search parameters), so serverPaging is set to true.

The transport property in the dataSource object is set.

For example:

```
$('#resultsGrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        pageSize    : 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        schema      : {
            total: 'total'
        },
        transport   : {
            read: {url: '../search.x'}
        }
    }
    /*... more options*/
});
```

However, an AJAX call (to ../search.x) is made to the server when the pages loads. How can I have the AJAX call be made when the search form is submitted and prevent it being called when the page loads? Also, how can I have transport read call the server with the original POST parameters of the search form when the next/previous page of results is requested?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about what you mean in the next/previous page section of your question.

Comment: By "next/previous page", I mean the next/previous page of results. For example, suppose that the search parameters result in a 1,000 rows of data. The server will only return say 10 rows of data (since pageSize in the above code is 10). The client will then display the 10 rows with an option to get the next 10 rows of data from the server. When the client makes the request to get the next 10 rows, I would like the search parameters to be given to the server so it can perform the query to get the next 10 rows. I hope that helps clarify, but please let me know if you need more information.Thanks

Comment: Ah ok I just wanted to confirm in case you wanted the parameters cleared since I wasn't sure if that's what you were asking for, since I've seen you've made a new question I'll answer/comment further on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `autoBind` to `false` in the Grid initialization. Documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-autoBind)

---

> *autoBind Boolean(default: true)*
>
> If set to false the widget **will not bind to the data source during initialization**. In this case data binding will occur when the change event of the data source is fired. By default the widget will bind to the data source specified in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai. That answers how I can prevent the call to ../search.x when the page loads. Do you know how I can call transport.read when a form is submitted? I have tried to make read point to a function and that function get the params of the form and make an AJAX call to the server. But  if I try to call $('#resultsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.transport.read({skip:0, take:10}) on form submission, I get two calls ../search.x (with the second call not passing any POST data).

Comment: Do [`grid.dataSource.read()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-read) or [`grid.dataSource.filter()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter) or [`grid.dataSource.fetch()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-fetch). Do you know that you don't need to invoke AJAX manually just because you need to send params to the server? Check [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) and [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data)

Comment: Thanks. read, query, and fetch dataSource functions work. I'm actually using [Malsup jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to automatically build the AJAX parameters from the search form. So, I'm setting transport.read to a function that has the following code: `var setupOptions = {success: loadSearch,type: 'POST',dataType: 'json',data: {skip: options.data.skip, take: options.data.take},url: '../search.x',error: errorHandler.handle, timeout: 50000};$('#searchForm').ajaxSubmit(setupOptions);`

Comment: It all seems to work except total is not properly being set. I have `schema: {total: 'total'}` set in the dataSource object and total property being returned json response. Do you know why total is not being set?

Comment: No, you might debug it by defining `total` as a function. In that function you can invoke `console.log` for displaying the actual data and even try returning a constant (as a double check).

Comment: OnaBai, Thanks again for your help. I'm marking your answer as the correct answer b/c I believe my issue now is different from the original question being asked (which you have answered). I would be very grateful if you wouldn't mind looking at my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225218/how-do-i-load-data-into-kendo-ui-grid-using-server-side-paging) which is a continuation of trying to get server side pagination to work with kendo,